# Memory leak issues

Tags: programming, simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, memory

I am working with noncommuting objects and basically I am using Mathematica to sort large expressions by normal ordering and simplifying them. To this end, I first create an object called `Boson` (These satisfy $[a,a^\dagger]=1$):

```
Clear[Boson, BosonC, BosonA]
Boson /: MakeBoxes[Boson[cr : (True | False), sym_], fmt_] := 
With[{sbox = If[StringQ[sym], sym, ToBoxes[sym]]}, 
With[{abox = 
 If[cr, SuperscriptBox[#, FormBox["\[Dagger]", Bold]], #] &@sbox},
InterpretationBox[abox, Boson[cr, sym]]]]
BosonA[sym_: String "a"] := Boson[False, sym]
BosonC[sym_: String "a"] := Boson[True, sym]
```

Next I alias the noncommutative product with `CenterDot` as follows:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
Clear[NonCommutativeMultiply, CenterDot];
CenterDot[a__] := NonCommutativeMultiply[a];
NonCommutativeMultiply /: 
MakeBoxes[NonCommutativeMultiply[a__], fmt_] := 
With[{cbox = ToBoxes[HoldForm[CenterDot[a]]]}, 
InterpretationBox[cbox, NonCommutativeMultiply[a]]]
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
Clear[CRule]
CRule = {NonCommutativeMultiply[a_] :> a};
```

Then I define the `Function` `clean` which does the normal ordering. It is defined in terms of `expand`. The main definition for `expand` is

```
ClearAll@expand
SetAttributes[expand, HoldAll]

Unevaluated[
  expand[expr_] :=
   Block[
    {NonCommutativeMultiply (*or times*)},

    expr //. (*ReplaceRepeated instead of ReplaceAll*)
     {times[left___, cnum_ /; FreeQ[cnum, (_Boson)], 
        right___] :> cnum*times[left, right], 
      times[left___, 
        cnum_ /; (! FreeQ[cnum, Times[n___?NumericQ, ___Boson]]), 
        right___] :> 
       Times @@ Apply[Power, Drop[FactorList[cnum], -1], 2]*
        times[left, First[Last[FactorList[cnum]]], right], 
      times[left___, Boson[False, s_], Boson[True, s_], right___] :> 
       times[left, right] + 
        times[left, Boson[True, s], Boson[False, s], right], 
      times[left___, fst : Boson[_, s_], sec : Boson[_, t_], 
        right___] :> 
       times[left, sec, fst, right] /; 
        FreeQ[Ordering[{s, t}], {1, 2}], times[b_Boson] :> b,
      times[] -> 1
      }
    ]
  ] /. {HoldPattern[times] -> NonCommutativeMultiply }
```

More definitions for expand are

```
expand[Alternatives[NonCommutativeMultiply, CenterDot][
a1_, (a2_ + a3_)]] := expand[a1 ** a2] + expand[a1 ** a3]
expand[Alternatives[NonCommutativeMultiply, CenterDot][(a1_ + a2_), 
a3_]] := expand[a1 ** a3] + expand[a2 ** a3]
```

Finally, the definition of `clean` is

```
Clear[clean]
clean = Simplify[FixedPoint[expand, Distribute //@ #] //. CRule] &;
```

This has been working very well for computing quartic terms but now the problem is that I am computing higher order terms which can involve products of up to 16 oscillators. When I use the `clean[]` function on those terms, the computation goes okay for a while but then the kernel starts using pretty much all the memory and it just stops doing anything else and I have quit the kernel. I am assuming that the `Module[]` function is not deleting the temporary variables and is leaking memory. I tried setting `$HistoryLength=0` but that didn't help either. What else can I do prevent this?

**Update:** I think the problem is in the implementation of `FixedPoint` in `clean`. If I manually apply `expand` and `Distribute` and then clear the cache and keep doing it till the computation doesn't take long (I take that as an indication that not much is changing), then I can finish the computation. This is a "dirty" fix but it would be nice to know if there is a way I can implement clearing the cache in `clean` along with `FixedPoint`.

**Update:** The data in one of the computations became so large that I kept running out of memory for everything and I had to keep dividing the expression into smaller and smaller parts to the point where it became hard to manage. Could be just that expressions are too big and I just don't have enough memory? Also edited the last block of code to remove a stray piece of code.

**Update:** [Here](http://pastebin.com/SRUN1kQe) is the full working notebook in pastebin.

Comment: Would there be the same problem if `Module` to be changed to `Block`?

Comment: Yes I already tried that. I am still not very sure of the exact differences but when I use `Module`, the memory seems to be around 300-400 MB for a minute and then quickly shoots up to 2.5GB or so and stalls. With `Block` it stays around 1.3GB and then shoots up and stalls.

Comment: The memory use behavior sounds very similar to what I stumbled on in a completely different context. Support suggested I try this http://support.wolfram.com/kb/11466 and that solved my problem. Can you try that and see whether it makes a difference? It doesn't require code changes and it is easy to undo the changes after the experiment.

Comment: @BillSimpson: I tried that and it didn't really help. I have seen this kind of problem on SE in some other questions without any clear solutions.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you replace `NonCommutativeMultiply` by `times` in order to avoid issues with the attribute `Flat`? To avoid this, you can simply use `expand[expr_] := Block[{NonCommutativeMultiply}, replacementCode]`, which temporarily disregards any attributes (as any other definitions) of `NonCommutativeMultiply`.

Comment: I am putting a working example of my code on pastebin. The aliasing with `CenterDot` was meant to make input/output a little more intuitive (especially for my advisor who also likes to "play" around with the code).

Comment: The suggestion that you made to use `With` and some other modifications does not work exactly how I want because of the way `timesRules` are written for now. I think you are right about `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` not getting replaced by 1 and I had made some quickfix to that by implementing `CRule` that I defined in the aliasing section.

Comment: Jacob, I missed your updates before I posted my comments. I did try `Block` and everything went same as with `Module`. So I am not exactly sure what is the main difference in `Block` vs `Module` in this context.

Comment: Karan, your statement "I am assuming that the `Module[]` function is not deleting the temporary variables and is leaking memory" is now outdated. I can assure you that the problem is also not that `Block` let's definitions leak. In fact, neither in the old code as well as in the new nor nontrivial definitions are made inside "scoping construct". I hope you are convinced and edit this statement :).

Comment: Another by the way: `Times[n___?NumericQ, ___Boson]` evaluates to `___Boson n___?NumericQ`. You should use `HoldPattern`, or perhaps you meant to write `times` here as well. It would really help if you could provide concise examples, the pastebin code is so long. Also I expect the memory problem to still occur, but maybe you should made sure, otherwise we may have prematurely changed your question.

Comment: Can you compare `ByteCount@clean[input]` with `MaxMemoryUsed[]` for an `input` that does not crash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very confusing mess of code. It seems to conmingle formatting with functionality, and that certainly does not make it straightforward to see what is wanted, let alone provide code. So what I show below could well be off the mark.

I basically copied and modified code for working with commutators avaliable [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/)

(Note to any colleagues of mine who might be reading this: Searching the site at library.wolfram.com remains an unfriendly task, many years after such things have become a "solved problem" in the "real world". Instead of navigating to the cite and trying my bad luck with a search, I should have just used Google. Unhappy that I'm calling you search engineer folks out on this? Feel free to drop by my office and punch me before I leave this evening.)

(Note to other readers: It's -10 F in Champaign today, or -23 C, and the place is empty. So I'm actually pretty safe. Also my office was move last August and nobody knows where to find me anymore. Or maybe nobody cares. Safe either way.)

So back to the code. I'm not sure all these rules are needed and some might be amiss or missing.

```
canonicalizeRules = {NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, Boson[False, y_], 
     Boson[True, y_], z___] :> 
    NonCommutativeMultiply[x, Boson[True, y], Boson[False, y], z] + 
     NonCommutativeMultiply[x, z],
   NonCommutativeMultiply[w___, Boson[tf1_, x_], Boson[tf2_, y_], 
      z___] /; (tf1 === tf2 || x =!= y) && Not[OrderedQ[{x, y}]] :>
      NonCommutativeMultiply[w, Boson[tf2, y], Boson[tf1, x], z],
   NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, y_, z___] /; 
     FreeQ[y, NonCommutativeMultiply | Boson] :> y*NonCommutativeMultiply[x, z],
   NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, y_NonCommutativeMultiply, z___] :> 
    NonCommutativeMultiply[x, Apply[Sequence, y], z],
   NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, y_*y2__, z___] /; 
     FreeQ[y, NonCommutativeMultiply | Boson] :> 
    y*NonCommutativeMultiply[x, y2, z],
   NonCommutativeMultiply[a_] /; Head[a] =!= Times :> a,
   NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, y_Plus, z___] :> 
    Map[NonCommutativeMultiply[x, #, z] &, y],
   NonCommutativeMultiply[] -> 1,
   NonCommutativeMultiply[a_, b_] /; 
     FreeQ[{a, b}, 
       NonCommutativeMultiply] && (FreeQ[a, Boson] || 
        FreeQ[b, Boson]) :> a*b,
   NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, y___, z___] /; FreeQ[{x, z}, Boson] :>
     x*z*NonCommutativeMultiply[y]};
```

I wrote it for NonCommutativeMultiply, then realized we're really using CenterDot. I guess. Anyway, I just changed the rules using a rule rule, and things started to evaluate as expected.

```
canonicalizeRules2 = 
  canonicalizeRules /. NonCommutativeMultiply -> CenterDot;
```

With these rules, `expand` and `clean` can be done as below.

```
expand[expr_] := Expand[expr //. canonicalizeRules2]
clean[expr_] := FixedPoint[expand, expr]

CommOp[x_, y_] := clean[(x\[CenterDot]y - y\[CenterDot]x)]; 
ACommOp[x_, y_] := clean[(x\[CenterDot]y + y\[CenterDot]x)];
```

I made another change in how various fellas were defined, mostly to use `List` rather than `DownValues`. From the interface view, the difference is in the double vs single bracket indexing. Under the hood of course is a different matter but that's outside the scope here.

```
GG = Table[
   Sum[\[CapitalSigma][i, j][[m, 
       n]] \[Chi][[1, m]]\[CenterDot]\[Psi][[n, 1]], {m, 1, 4}, {n, 1,
      4}], {i, 1, Dim}, {j, 1, Dim}];

MM = Table[GG[[i, j]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
KK = Table[GG[[i, 6]] - GG[[i, 5]], {i, 1, 4}];
\[CapitalPi] = Table[GG[[i, 6]] + GG[[i, 5]], {i, 1, 4}];
\[CapitalDelta] = -GG[[5, 6]];
```

One last thing to observe is that since `g` is a diagonal matrix, many sums can be shortened considerably by contracting indices. I show such a computation with `Cas2b`.

```
Cas2b = clean[
   Sum[g[[ind1, ind1]]\[CenterDot]GG[[ind1, ind2]]\[CenterDot]g[[ind2,
        ind2]]\[CenterDot]GG[[ind2, ind1]], {ind1, 1, 6}, {ind2, 1, 
     6}]];
```

The result is failry short.

```
6 - (3 Boson[True, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, a])/2 - (
 3 Boson[True, b]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, b])/2 - (
 3 Boson[True, x]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, x])/2 - (
 3 Boson[True, y]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, y])/2 - 
 3 Boson[True, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   True, b]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, b] + 
 3 Boson[True, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   True, x]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, x] + 
 3 Boson[True, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   True, y]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, y] - 
 3/2 Boson[True, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[True, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   False, a]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, a] + 
 3 Boson[True, b]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, b]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   True, x]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, x] + 
 3 Boson[True, b]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, b]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   True, y]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, y] - 
 3/2 Boson[True, b]\[CenterDot]Boson[True, b]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   False, b]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, b] - 
 3 Boson[True, x]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, x]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   True, y]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, y] - 
 3/2 Boson[True, x]\[CenterDot]Boson[True, x]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   False, x]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, x] - 
 3/2 Boson[True, y]\[CenterDot]Boson[True, y]\[CenterDot]Boson[
   False, y]\[CenterDot]Boson[False, y]
```

I do not know if it is correct but at least it is not in any obvious (to myself) way wrong.

--- edit ---

I also mention that it could be safer/faster to use a table, then total it, with `clean` applied to the summands. This way we know that no individual term is overly large, hence one can hope for relatively straightforward, fast, pattern matching.

Here is an example. I also use the contracting of indices.

```
Timing[cas4c = 
   Table[clean[
     g[[ind1, ind1]] g[[ind2, ind2]] g[[ind3, ind3]] g[[ind4, 
        ind4]] GG[[ind1, ind2]]\[CenterDot]GG[[ind2, 
         ind3]]\[CenterDot]GG[[ind3, ind4]]\[CenterDot]GG[[ind4, 
         ind1]]], {ind1, 1, 6}, {ind2, 1, 6}, {ind3, 1, 6}, {ind4, 1, 
     6}];]

(* {423.500000, Null} *)
```

It's big...

```
cas4c // LeafCount

(* Out[362]= 2916979 *)
```

... but it collapses nicely.

```
cas4d = Total[Flatten[cas4c]];
cas4d // LeafCount

(* Out[364]= 1689 *)
```

There are ways to get further contraction by grouping identical consecutive NonCommutativeMultiply factors in powers, say.

Also I will repeat that the rules I used might be overkill and might contain subtle (or not so subtle) bottlenecks. So there is likely to be room for improvement in terms of speed as well as size of result.

--- end edit ---

Comment: Next time I'm in Champaign, I'll have to hunt you down. :D

Comment: @rcollyer We've relocated to the Siberian Steppes, to hear the weather folks describe it. My kid says it's an ordinary day for Ft Mac and we whine too much. Both of which, sad to say, are true.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think there is some extra stuff in the `canonicalizeRules2` definition. I tried to use your modifications to see the results but the product is not behaving distributively. Its strange because the answer that you computed for `Cas2b` is correct and same as what I had gotten previously. I exactly copied your rules but still I don't know what's going wrong in my notebook.

Comment: I'll fix the cut/paste error. If that doesn't do the job then I'll recheck tomorrow. I went through several debug cycles and it's possible the code I posted for `canonicalizeRules` was not the final version.

Comment: @Daniel The distributive rule didn't work till I put it at the top of the list in 'canonicalizeRules'. Could you tell me what caused that?

Comment: Offhand I do not know but possibly this one appearing higher up was causing trouble: ` NonCommutativeMultiply[x___, y_, z___] /; 
     FreeQ[y, NonCommutativeMultiply | Boson] :> y*NonCommutativeMultiply[x, z]`

Answer (score 1):

*This is really an extended comment, not an answer to the question. But who knows, maybe this solves the problem anyway. Also I guess this solves a more important question than the one asked by the OP as I guess the code was broken before.*

I would rewrite your last code block as

```
ClearAll@expand
(*the attribute is new*)
SetAttributes[expand, HoldAll]

Unevaluated[
  expand[expr_] :=
   Block[
    {NonCommutativeMultiply (*or times*)}
    ,
    expr /.
     {
      times[left___, cnum_ /; FreeQ[cnum, (_Boson)], right___] :> 
       cnum*times[left, right]
      ,
      times[left___, 
        cnum_ /; (! 
           FreeQ[cnum, Unevaluated@Times[n___?NumericQ, ___Boson]]), 
        right___] :>
       Times @@ Apply[Power, Drop[FactorList[cnum], -1], 2]*
        times[left, FactorList[cnum][[-1,1]], right]
      ,
      times[left___, Boson[False, s_], Boson[True, s_], right___] :> 
       times[left, right] + 
        times[left, Boson[True, s], Boson[False, s], right]
      ,
      times[left___, fst : Boson[_, s_], sec : Boson[_, t_], 
        right___] :> 
       times[left, sec, fst, right] /; 
        FreeQ[Ordering[{s, t}], {1, 2}]
      ,
      times[b_Boson] :> b
      ,
      times[] -> 1
      }
    ]
  ] /. {HoldPattern[times] -> NonCommutativeMultiply }
```

And

```
(*Not equivalent to your code, this is a fix*)
expand[Alternatives[NonCommutativeMultiply, CenterDot][
   a1_, (a2_ + a3_)]] := expand[a1 ** a2] + expand[a1 ** a3]
expand[Alternatives[NonCommutativeMultiply, CenterDot][(a1_ + a2_), 
   a3_]] := expand[a1 ** a3] + expand[a2 ** a3]
```

This fixes only minor issues with memory, but it makes the last definitions for expand useful. Note that your definition already had the nice property that `expr` was evaluated inside the `Module` (and now inside `Block`), so that any aliases `Centerdot` will be replaced by `NonCommutativeMultiply` before the rules in terms of times are applied.

If you saw that I was hinting at using `With`, and you are curious about how stuff stuff work `ReplaceAll` and `Unevaluated` works, my explanation is that this basically an alternative way to write `With`. The reason I do this is that `With` is a scoping construct, and it tries to resolve conflicts between variables, which was undesirable in this case.

Comment: If you agree that this is nice, please replace the code in your question and I will delete the answer, as well as any comments that hinted at this, in order to clean things up and attack the real problem.

Comment: Jacob, I agree this is neater looking and more efficient. I will replace this in my code on pastebin.

Comment: Jacob, I just noticed the changes and was in the process of changing things. It should be fine now.

Comment: @Karan I will keep the answer for now. Also note that I have added an `Unevaluated` around `Times` inside `FreeQ`